# Determine if Laravel Eloquent relation returns one or many

Tags: php, api, laravel, relationship, eloquent

Given the following code,

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

a request to `/api/posts?embed=comments,author` should return all posts with related comments and the post author embedded / nested in the response.

I can fetch the related item(s) using `$related = $post->getRelation($relation_name)` but what is the best way of checking if this returns a Collection or a single Eloquent model?

Checking the returned type seems easiest (`$related instanceof Collection`) but I understand this a bad practice.

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't this be solved by simply using $related->count()?

Comment: @Genie count() doesn't help me because (1) it won't always be a defined method in cases where relations return a single Eloquent model, and (2) the actual number of records found is not important, it's whether or not the _type_ of relationship is `*-to-one` or `*-to-many`.

Comment: Use $post->comments and you will get a Collection

Comment: @marcanuy, yes but that's not the question (apologies if unclear). I'm building an API and trying to implement nested relations in a generic way. I included the Post class definition as an illustration - in reality, I'm working with `$model` and `$relation_name` variables. 

All I know is `$model` is an `Eloquent` subclass and `$relation_name` is the name of a method defining a relation (which in the example would be `comments` or `author`).